# Intercept and override where clause of linq

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am in a situation where I cannot add new params to a method, and cannot change the logic of DataQuery either - so I can only change the content of the methods with a similar construction as this, and the properties of T.

```
IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(DataQuery<T> query) {
  var collection = repo;
  return query.Apply(repo).ToList();
}
```

My problem is that I want to add support for retrieving Ts assigned to my team, or my company or just me, but I do not have access to any context of "me" from the calling point - they are available on UserContext in the methods.

The `DataQuery<T>.Apply()` allows me to query on Ts properties like `T.caseId <= 4` and will return a list with cases 1-4. which are translated into `source.Where(t => t.caseId <= 4)`

My idea is to add the following fields to T

```
bool IsMineQuery
bool IsMyTeamQuery
bool IsMyCompanyQuery
```

and then intercept the calls to `.Where(t => t.IsMineQuery == true)` or `.Where(t => t.IsMyTeamQuery == true)` and rewrite them to `.Where(t => t.UserId == UserContext.UserId)` or `.Where(t => UserContext.TeamIds.Contains(t.TeamId))` but I have no idea of how to intercept the calls.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I might not have fully understood your question, but shouldn't `bool IsMineQuery { get { return UserId == UserContext.UserId } }` suffice?

Comment: @Heinzi No, because `UserContext` is not available inside `IsMyQuery` getter.

Comment: What is `DataQuery<T>`? Do you have control over it? How do you constructing and the query?

Comment: I do not have control of DataQuery<T> - It is some magic that converts a query string into several .Where()'s on the provided data source (repo) - I am able to do filtering on beforehand to the data source, i.e. repo.where(t => t.State == 'open') but I do not have access to the raw query string.

Comment: It sounds impossible for me

Comment: I cannot see that it is much different than what AutoMappers .ProjectTo does - their code is however almost Greek to me.

Comment: T is a placeholder for a generic type, what do you mean add fields to T? Create an interface with those fields and make it a constraint on T?

Comment: Yes, T in this case is just a bunch of DTOs that I actually have control over, and hence is able to fiddle with.

Comment: So why not do `repo.Where(t => t.UserId == UserContext.UserId)` before passing it in?

Comment: Not sure your question, are `IsMineQuery`, `IsMyTeamQuery` already exist? Do you want to change what they return?

Comment: @NetMage - because I at the time could identify if the DataQuery<T> will apply .Where(t => t.IsMineQuery) or not - that is based on the calling system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after fidling around all night I had a break through.

I had to make a custom query provider - I used this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

then my controllers are of the form

```
IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(DataQuery<T> query) {
  var collection = new MyQueryable(repo, UserContext);
  return query.Apply(repo).ToList();
}
```

Then I have changed the tutorial's "InnerMostWhereFinder" to identify if my query has gotten a IsMineQuery or IsMyTeamQuery and replace it with UserContext.TeamIds.Contain(x => x.Team.Id)
Works like a charm, but was not an straight forward solution.